# Angular 8 (nebular) populating select options on subscription

Tags: angular, select, nebular

I have a small `<nb-select>` that should get its values from the database.

In the constructor I have:

```
this.server.getExperimentsUser(this.user.idUser).subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log(response);
  this.experiments = response.map(x => {
    return {
      name: x.name,
      id: x.idExperiment
    };
  });
  console.log(this.experiments);
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<nb-select ([ngModel])="currentExperiment" (selectedChange)="changeExperiment($event)" status="primary" placeholder="Select experiment">
  <nb-option *ngFor="let e of experiments" [value]="e.id"> {{ e.name }} </nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

So by my (faulty, apprently) logic, after the call has been made, `this.experiments` is changed and the options should populate inside the `<nb-select>`. The call does work as intended, because the `console.log()`s return the correct object.

I only need to populate the select once, that's why I have put the subscribe in the constructor.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Change detection doesn't happen for subscription responses. That's the reason even after you get proper response it doesnt reflect in the DOM.  Try changing the code like this.

```
    this.server.getExperimentsUser(this.user.idUser).subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.experiments = response.map(x => {
        return {
          name: x.name,
          id: x.idExperiment
        };
      });
      ref.detechChanges();
      console.log(this.experiments);
    }
```

And in your constructor

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Also can u change the html like below

```
<nb-option *ngFor="let e of experiments" value="e.id"> {{ e.name }} </nb-option>
```

Comment: I had already set it on the ngAfterViewInit(), but even doing it earlier like that doesn't change the behavior, the options don't populate

Comment: I can't seem to be able to replicate the error in stackblitz, it works perfectly fine even without the ChangeDetectorRef, which makes me wonder if there is some other module conflicting with it in my real case

Comment: Ah! I made it work! But I don't understand why. If I use `.subscribe(this.callbackFunction)` it does not work, as it used the function before the sunscribe ends. It works if I do `.subscribe(response => {...})`